# How to go about a type checker in prolog?

Tags: prolog, typechecking

So I am new to prolog and I am suppose to implement a type checker. How exactly should I go about it? This would be an example:

```
String s; int i; i = s.length(); // OK (example given in the homework)
```

When I asked the professor how things will be input, it would look something like this:

```
instance(s, string).
```

Thats great, except if this is done, the unification for i is lost at the close of the query, so if I were to make a say, equals fact and call it like so,

```
equals(i, s, '.', 'length').
```

how can i check what i is. So I am just having a hard time knowing where to start. Its a homework, so just want some advice, help on kind of understanding how to go about my first prolog project. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Assignment

Write a Prolog program that can type check the method calls for a given Java program
according to the JLS . The fact base can be any encoding of the methods defined in any
non-trivial Java program you have written, plus, minimally, those listed below. In query
mode, it must check potential matches; for example allowing "println(string)." You need 
not encode those JLS rules that you don't need. (One of the examples given is above.)

Comment: Implementing a type checker in Prolog for a language like Java is definitely not an adequate first assignment in  Prolog. You have to learn Prolog first!

Comment: This is how its been the whole semester with a few languages! Oh wells. I agree, not the best way to learn.

Comment: @Andy: please add more info about your homework, atm it's unclear what is asked and we cannot truly help

Comment: I'll add the assignment, but I am not sure it will be helpful. What I gave in my question is literally all we got from the professor. But i'll add the assignment. I am essentially asking how to make a type checker. But with what I provided above, I don't really know how to go about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I intended what follows as a starting point. Here is my formalisation:

```
type(string).
```

means that string is an available type for a variable to be an instance of

```
signature(=, [X, X, nil]).
```

means that the infix operator = takes two arguments of same type and returns nothing.

```
is_instance(X, Y)
```

means that `X` is an instance of type `Y`
To test things out, I created a list of "statements" contained in my variable `Input` of my `test/0` predicate. Then I recursively test out if things are well. You have to implement the third clause as a recursive call to find out if types are ok in expressions now.

What I did atm is that in my first main `check/2` clause, I handle `instance/2` terms, and in the following one, all the rest.

```
:- dynamic is_instance/2.

type(string).
type(int).

signature(=, [X, X, nil]).

test :-
    retractall(is_instance(_, _)),
    Input = [instance(s, string), instance(i, int), =(i, length(s))],
    check(Input, ReturnTypes),

check([], []).
check([instance(Variable, Type)|Terms], [nil|ReturnTypes]) :-
    !,
    ( is_instance(Variable, _) -> syntax_error('Variable already declared')
    ; \+ type(Type) -> syntax_error('Using a non-existing type'),
    ; Term =.. [is_instance, Variable, Type],
      assertz(Term)),
    check(Terms, ReturnTypes).

check([Term|Terms], [Type|ReturnTypes]) :-
    Term =.. [Name|Arguments],
    % Here we have to call ourselves with our list of arguments
    % and then check that everything is fine and then we'll unify Type
    % with the return value of Name.
    check(Terms, ReturnTypes).
```

I hope it'll help to get you started.

Comment: Wow, thats a lot of stuff I am not too sure of as I am new at this language. But yes, I greatly appreciate the time you put into the answer. I am confused about signature though. Above you had a third argument, nil, and in the code you don't have that argument. Am I missing something? But again, this gives me a starting point in which to do lots of research and get the homework done.